iOS build is getting rejected on AppStoreConnect, with tdLib
I ran into this problem while uploading my flutter app on App Store Connect:
Introductory: my application uses the tdlib library (for telegram), complied in libtdjson.xcframework for iOS containing libtdjson.1.8.39.dylib for ios-arm64 architecture, placed inside the Framework folder, swift compilation is active and also all the necessary header files are in place, along with the C++ & Swift bridge and my methods are written in AppDelegate.swift and is accessed via method channels on flutter side. Also have generated and added libtdjson.1.8.39.dylib.dSYM for symbols as required.
The ios build is successfully archived and uploaded, but on the appStoreConnect console under TestFlight builds, new build is not shown, and receive an email from apple stating :
An error occurs: ITMS-90429: Invalid Swift Support - The files libswift_Concurrency.dylib aren’t at the expected location /Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.
Recompiling the tdLib according to the given instructions on https://github.com/tdlib/td/tree/master/example/ios did not help.
Do let me know if the compilation needs to be done in a specific way, such that this error can be resolved, or do tell the steps you followed to run tdLib on iOS.

You are uploading app using Xcode Beta version? Always upload app using Xcode from App Store.

This question is similar to: Error: Invalid Swift Support when uploading a build to iTunes Connect. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MartinZeitler my issue is not being resolved by any of the solutions stated in  Error: Invalid Swift Support when uploading a build to iTunes Connect.As mentioned above  my configurations are set : Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries is enabled, header files are in place and accessible, and .dylib files are embedded and signed.

@FahimParkar - have tried uploading via Xcode as well as using github actions and fastLane via automation. Nothing seems to be working.

Can you confirm, that /Payload/Runner.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib exists within that package? I honestly have no clue of iOS, but this is what the error message suggests.
